# No such file or directory export 'src/material/page.dart' MaterialPageRoute build issues

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I recently got back into an app I had been working on. Without any changed MaterialPageRoute has broken. I get build issues every time I try to debug.

The two uses I have in the app are:

```
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TimeEditScreen(data: {'id': rowData['id'], 'type': rowData['event_type'], 'date': rowData['date'],
        'startTime': rowData['time_in'] != null ? DateTime.parse(rowData['time_in']) : null, 'endTime': rowData['time_out'] != null ? DateTime.parse(rowData['time_out']) : null, 
        'breakMinutes': rowData['break_minutes'], 'day': rowData['day'], 'month': rowData['month'], 'ordinal': rowData['ordinal']})
      )
    );
```

and

```
      onUnknownRoute: (RouteSettings setting) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => ActionsScreen()
        );
      },
```

Like I said I haven't changed a thing and when I left it it was working. I am at a loss.

These are the errors upon debug:

[image]

All help is great appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this I had to `flutter clean` and then `flutter upgrade --force`.